# Increasing Value of Array of Strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an assignment where I pass a string into a function with the definition `char *get_word( char **string_ptr);`

My main will stop calling the function when the string that was passed points to the `'\0'` character. Therefore I have to implement this line inside the function: `*string_ptr += strlen( *string_ptr );`

This is very confusing to me. I am under the impression that `*string_ptr` would be the string that is being passed in the function. So what would it mean to increase the value of that?

Another question. If `**string_ptr` is an array of strings then what would be `*string_ptr` or just `string_ptr` on it's own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay first of all, `**string_ptr` semantically does not guarantee that `string_ptr` is going to be an array of strings or an array of char pointers. This comes clear after memory management is handled.

To your function you are passing a pointer to string as far as I understood.
So you do something like that

```
char* string = "my string in read-only memory";

foo(&string);
```

To access the value of the string the pointer points to, you dereference the pointer and then dereference the string. This resolves to the first character of the string.

`**string_ptr` is the first character of your string.

`*string_ptr` is string

`string_ptr` is pointer to string.

---

There is much clearer or at least more understandable way to do what you want to achieve:

```
char* p = *string_ptr;

for(char* p = *string_ptr; *p != '\0' p++);
```

you create new pointer to the string

then increment it until it points to the address that holds the `\0`

---

Adding more `*` to a variable just means that it points to another thing.

```
char* ch; // ch points to char or string
char** ch; // ch points to char*
char*** ch; // ch points to char**
```

and so on

---

> *string_ptr would be the string that is being passed in the function. So what would it mean to increase the value of that?

You are correct about that.
Increasing value of a pointer usually means performing pointer arithmetics on the variable. Essentially it is the same as if you increment regular variable, but this time this is performed on an address value, where increase of 1 means increase of `1 * sizeof(type)`

I demonstrated what incrementing pointer is and what it does.

---

`*string_ptr += strlen( *string_ptr );`

since `*string_ptr` is the string offset
This would make your string point to the end of itself.
So it would be good if you obtain an additional reference of it before that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an assignment where I pass a string into a function with the
>   [prototype] `char *get_word( char **string_ptr);`
>
> My main will stop calling the function when the string that was passed
>   points to the '/0' character.

It is important to distinguish between a *string*, which is a null-terminated *array* of `char`, and a *pointer* to (the first character of) a string, which is how strings are conveyed to functions and returned from them, and very often how strings are accessed in general.  A `char *` pointing to the first character of a string is separate from and independent of the string itself.  Your statement therefore makes sense only when interpreted as "My main will stop calling the function when the value of the pointer variable whose address was passed points to the '/0' character of the string."

> Therefore I have to implement this line
>   inside the function: `*string_ptr += strlen( *string_ptr )`;

That would indeed update the pointer value at the address to which `string_ptr` points so that it points to the terminator of the string to which it initially pointed.  I'm inclined to suppose, however, that that is *not* what you actually want because then there would be no need to call the function more than once.  If the function unconditionally executed that statement then the passed pointer would always point to the terminator after the just one call.

> This is very confusing to me. I am under the impression that
>   `*string_ptr` would be the string that is being passed in the function. So what would it mean to increase the value of that?

`*string_ptr` is whatever `string_ptr` points to.  With the declaration you present, that would be a pointer of type `char *`.  Remember: it is important to distinguish between such a pointer and the thing (the first character of a string in this case) to which it points.  Increasing the value of the pointer simply makes it point to some later character in the string (as long as you don't increase it too much).  If you increase it by the full count of characters in the string, then it will point to the terminator.

> Another question. If `**string_ptr` is an array of strings then what
>   would be `*string_ptr` or just `string_ptr` on it's own?

Considered as expressions, `*string_ptr` and `**string_ptr` are meaningless out of context.  With the declaration you provided, however, the expression `*string_ptr` evaluates to the `char *` pointed to by `string_ptr`.  The expression `**string_ptr` evaluates to the `char` pointed to by the `char *` pointed to by `string_ptr`.  `string_ptr` itself is simply the value of the function's argument, which is declared to be a pointer to pointer to `char`.

But I think you're actually asking about the function prototype, in which case you've asked the wrong question.  The usual question is about whether the type (`char **`) of parameter `string_ptr` represents an array of strings.  The answer is "no" on several levels, and "maybe, sort of" on at least one.

On its face, type `char **` represents a pointer to pointer to char.  This *can be* a pointer to the first `char *` in an array of `char *`, and that's what it will be if you present such an array as the corresponding argument.  It is by no means certain that the pointed-to `char *` is a member of an array, however, and if it is, no information is conveyed about the length of that array.  There is no meaningful distinction between such a pointer pointing to a single, scalar `char *` and it pointing to the first and only element of a one-member array of `char *`.

The same distinction applies one level down, of course.  A valid `char *` *often* points to the first `char` of a string, but you don't know that from the type alone.  Supposing such a pointer is valid, it might instead point into an unterminated array of `char`, or to a single, scalar `char`.  For type `char *` in particular, it may also point (in)to the raw bytes of the value of an object of any other type, too.